# Navigation using Ctrl + Click for PHP in VSCode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there is a way to enable HyperLink with ctrl-click like PHPStorm and Eclipse for PHP files
require_once ("mainfile.php");
include_once ('lib/nusoap/nusoap.php');

And if there is any extension that also allows you to go-to-definition
With Eclipse and PhpStorm i can navigate between functions and files easily...
The problem is: they're too heavy, so i choose VS Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm developing an extension like this for PHP right now.
This can't work in all scenarios as you can use functions or constants when declaring paths. e.g.

```
MAIN_DIR . get_template_directory() . 'file.php'
```

And u can get these paths from external resources (even parsing the whole app won't always work).
If u have multiple 'file.php' in different directories I can't resolve this.

Edit: the extension will give you now a list of files to choose from.
But if a 'file.php' or 'dir/file.php' relates to only one file I can link it.
I'm checking/matching file names and paths with active workspace files.

[PHP File Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pwarchol.vscode-php-file-link)

Comment: Ok. Did you finish the extension?

Comment: It's still in progress but I just released version 0.3 which should be the first stable one.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks.